# org-mode latex preview not working -newbie

Tags: latex, org-mode, preview

I have recently installed org-mode for emacs through its package manager, and for some reason the latex-previewing feature does not work. I've tried both imagemagick and dvipng.

The message that I get when I try [C-c C-x C-l] is: "Symbol's function definition is void: org-infile-export-plist." I'm relatively new to emacs so I'm not sure how to proceed. I've been googling for about 2 hours and I haven't found anyone with a similar problem.

I have the latest version of emacs and org-mode 7.9. I checked about mixed installation issues (as suggested by the org manual) and everything checks out. I'm running Linux mint 17.

Can someone suggest a solution?

ps: I've tried AucTex and that works, but I think it only works on .tex files, not on .org files.

**Edit**: since I made the post I've found out that several other commands are giving me the same error (with different variables after the colon). Is there something wrong with my installation?

Comment: yes, the current version of org-mode is more like 8.2.10 when installed from ELPA. I guess you are using an older version somehow.

Comment: I will try updating but somehow I don't think that's the problem. That's the standard version that comes with emacs, and I would think those basic features would work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issue while trying to solve a bug in org-mode on spacemac, preview-toggle-latex-fragment which apparently causing the bug when the stack is in this order

- spacemac 0.200.13
- emacs-plus 25.3_2
- org-plus-contrib-20180521

a few of this solution might come in handy, it didn't work for but it definitely gave me a broader view of the situation I'm facing

- [org-mode-9-unable-to-eval-code-block](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28441/org-mode-9-unable-to-eval-code-blocks/28604#28604)
- [org-latex-preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30151338/org-latex-preview-is-fuzzy-on-retina-displays)

As I google-fu my way through, I stumbled upon a issue posted on [d12frosted/homebrew-emacs](https://github.com/d12frosted/homebrew-emacs-plus/issues/10), which sort of convince me to give [mituharu/emacs-mac](https://bitbucket.org/mituharu/emacs-mac) a try and it turned out that it worked really well out of the box and solve the problem.

---

My current working configuration for my (org-mode + latex) would be

- spacemacs 0.300.0 ( dev branch )
- [emacs-mac 26.1](https://github.com/railwaycat/homebrew-emacsmacport)
- +emacs/org ( spacemac layer )

  - org-plus-contrib-20180521
- latex-math-preview (elpa)
- dvipng ( it wasn't on brew, it came with TexLive)

  ```
  $ tlmgr install dvipng
  ```
- [TeXLive](http://www.tug.org/mactex/)

Once you've solved the problem, you might find this helpful as well.
[auto preview latex fragment](https://gist.github.com/cvcore/760008a4dfb2eadf42afdc9cf01ef979)

Answer (score 0):

This is old but since I had the same issue, maybe it'll help someone else. This happens because the Org export functions haven't been loaded. Try doing export and cancelling it with the sequence `C-c C-e q` this will cause `ox` (Org export) to be loaded, and latex preview should now work. If that fixes your issue, add this to your .emacs:

```
;; Preload org export functions, needed for latex preview. 
(require 'ox)
```